# where to get SAPI?

Tags: mfc, speech-recognition, sapi, speech

i want to create an application that is speech-enabled but whenever i get to MS website to download SAPI, i get an error.

I want to know where I can get SAPI.

and I also would like to know if a SAPI 5.3 application can work on Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Vista (if coded with C++/MFC).

also, what is the best way to use SAPI ? with C# .NET or C++/MFC ?

Thanks.

Comment: What, precisely, are you trying to download and from where? What error do you encounter? The SAPI SDK 5.1 appears downloadable from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530

Answer (score 4):

The [Microsoft Speech SDK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_Application_Programming_Interface) is availabe for download [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=5e86ec97-40a7-453f-b0ee-6583171b4530&displaylang=en).

Whether to choose C# or C++ depends on your own preferences. When using .NET you will find everything related to speech recogition and synthesis in `System.Speech`. Add a reference to this assembly to your project and you will be able to use the Speech API directly. The following is a simple sample program demonstrating the text-to-speech functionality:

```
using System.Speech.Synthesis;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
        synth.Rate = -1;
        synth.Volume = 100;

        synth.SelectVoice("Microsoft Sam");

        synth.Speak("Hello World");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you can download just Speech SDK 5.3 from the microsoft website. You can download windows platform SDK from http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en that includes SAPI 5.3.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you get SAPI from MS.  If they have a problem serving, you have a problem downloading!

I used SAPI with C, so I can't comment on C#/C++.

Also it was some years ago, so I don't know which version I used - but it ran fine on w2k, FWIW.